# How to list all aws s3 objects which the current user has permission to acess?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with objects structure like below:

```
S3://0/10/20.txt (I have permission to list 20.txt)
S3://0/11/21.txt (I DON't have permission to list 21.txt)
S3://0/12/22.txt (I have permission to list 22.txt)
```

How can I run a AWS CLI command to list ALL objects in this bucket which I have permission to list?

I tried to run the following and got a Access Denied error.

```
aws s3 ls s3://0/ --recursive
```

Thank you.

**Update:**

I should have made it clear that I can list specific objects which I have permissions to list like below:

```
aws s3 ls S3://0/10/20.txt (this works fine)
aws s3 ls s3://0/ --recursive (this does not work)
```

My goal is to list the objects from the bucket which I have permission to list. My expected results for the command (aws s3 ls s3://0/ --recursive) are:

```
S3://0/10/20.txt
S3://0/12/22.txt
```

**Update 2:**

I thought read and list are the same permission but it seems it's not. Therefore I've updated my descriptions to reflect what I really want which is to recusively list the objects from the bucket which I have permission to list(ignore the ones which I don't have permission to list).

Comment: What about your permissions on the bucket itself(not on the items in it)?

Comment: Do you actually want to know which files you can access, or are you simply trying to debug a situation to figure out why you don't have total access? You should start by looking at the Bucket Policy, then the permissions on your own IAM User, and also the permissions on the objects themselves. What is your ultimate goal — do you simply want to have access to all the objects?

Comment: My goal is to list only the objects I have permission to read in the bucket. I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't think there is a clean answer.  If you can call `get-bucket-policy`, you can see which prefixes you can enumerate, but even then, it's entirely possible to grant permission to get an object but not list it.  I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: I thought read and list are the same permission but it seems they are not. I've updated my question. I only need to list all objects which I have permission to list.

Comment: The permission models in Amazon S3 are complex and you often won't know if you have a particular permission until you try it. For example, it is possible to create permissions that only allow access from a particular IP address. This means that your ability to read/list the objects will depend upon your IP address when you make the request. It is more straight-forward to look at the Bucket Policy and IAM permissions to determine the rules applied.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  S3 doesn't know which objects you have permission to read until you actually try to read them.

The List Objects APIs don't know whether you can access an object, only whether you are allowed to request the object listings, which is a separate permission that is completely unrelated to whether you can actually read the object.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I thought read and list are the same permission but it seems they are not. I've updated my question. I only need to list all objects which I have permission to list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the bucket permissions although you have permissions to read some of the files. Try to apply this policy if you don't have list object permissions on your S3 bucket

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:ListBucket"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::yourBucketName"
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Juned Ahsan, I've updated my question. My goal is to list only the objects I have permission to read in the bucket.

Comment: @Allen reading the objects in the bucket permission  is different from listing the bucket content. I have put in the policy above for adding permissions to list objects. If you have the appropriate permissions, then your issue maybe something else

Comment: Thanks Juned, I thought read and list are the same permission but it seems they are not. I've updated my question. I only need to list all objects which I have permission to list.